# What is the conditions to use a weights argument to a linear model, when the dependent variable is a proportion?

Tags: r, regression, density-function, linear, weights

My data consists of the independent variable (x) which is slope gradient (°) and the dependent variable (y) is collar GPS point density/km². For each slope gradient, the independent variable was calculated by the number of GPS points divided by the number of pixels present in the reserve. I wanted to run a linear model with a weighted argument to account for the overrepresentation of some slope gradients across the reserve. So I had the following formula: lm(GPS points density ~ Slope gradient, data=GPS.data, weights = Nb of pixels found in the reserve).

I was wondering if this is correct knowing that I am using the same variable (nb of pixel in the reserve for each slope gradient) to weight my model and to calculate my density variable.

Sorry if this is a bit hard to understand!

Thank you for any suggestions :)